# Running spark on EMR, some job status showing "undefined"

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have a spark job done on EMR cluster, the job is pretty simple, reading from some parquet files, do the union and dropDuplication kind of work. 
When the cluster is done, it shows me the cluster status with "All steps completed". I looked into the "Application History"->"Job" tab, found that not all tasks have been done.

I went to the "Stage" tab, there are some "undefined" stages and "unknown" tasks,
does anyone know what was going on there? The cluster seems to tell me "all the jobs have been done", why there are "undefined" stages and "unknown" tasks remain?